# Samples or live demo of Amazon Polly?

Tags: text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I'm considering using Amazon Polly's Text-To-Speech (TTS) but want to evaluate how natural it really sounds with arbitrary examples (not the ones carefully curated by Amazon marketing folks).

All I've found is a [very limited youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtGaVrkkD38) (just a few seconds in each of the languages)

Comment: You can check this YouTube Video for Amazon Polly voice samples  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=00D0YZ9GQX4&t=13s

Comment: There are public demos here: https://ai-service-demos.go-aws.com/polly

Answer (score 11):

Log into your AWS account, then you can experiment with different voices here: https://console.aws.amazon.com/polly/home/SynthesizeSpeech

Answer (score 2):

If have an AWS account, you can test all the languages and voices yourself. Just go to the homepage of the console and search for polly. You can write anything you like, change the file format and download it too.

[Here's how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqazi.png)

Answer (score -6):

most of the amazon voices are not amazon voices i mean they are third party voices the sample provided is: acapela justin and there are other  companyes like ivona,acapela, rspeak and much more. ,

Comment: I don't see how this matters to OP at all.